# How to trim a string between two known values and remove all runs of any kind of whitespace and replace them with a single space

Tags: c#, regex, string

I would like to remove the values between a string and the known values and any exrtra white spaces, new lines tabs and replace those with a single space i.e

```
"<username            type ='string'> DGodfrey </username>        <password type = 'string' > mypass </password></MobileLogin>";
```

and replace with

```
"<username type = 'string' > DGodfrey </username></MobileLogin>";
```

I believe the code for my regex is correct as it solves the issues individually but im not sure how to do it all in one line

heres my progress so far

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    string q = "<root type='object'> < Items type = 'array' >< item type = 'object' >< Identity type = 'object' >< Identifier type = 'string' > MQH37KARHXAFE8V </ Identifier ></ Identity > <MobileLogin type='object'>< username type = 'string' > DGodfrey </ username >< password type = 'string' > mypass </ password ></ MobileLogin ></ Items > ";
    var d = GetBetweenTwoWords(q);
    Console.WriteLine(d);
}
public static string GetBetweenTwoWords(string context)
{
    return Regex.Replace(context, "password(.*?)password" + @"\s+", " ");
}
```

Comment: str = str.replace("\\s\\s+", " ");

Answer (score 0):

this got the job done

```
 public static string GetBetweenTwoWords(string context)
        {
            return Regex.Replace(context, "password(.*?)password | \\s+", " ");
        }
```

Comment: No idea how to get rid of the "<" and ">"

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string GetBetweenTwoWords(string context)
{
  return Regex.Replace(context, "\\<\\s*password(.*?)password\\s*\\>|\\s+", " ");
}
```

This removes anything that is contained in the `<password>` tags, while of course replacing any whitespace with a space.